# Magento 2.4 header.phtml file issue

Tags: magento

In my Magento 2.4 platform . I have  my `header.phml` in below location:
`/var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/MyPackage/MyTheme/templates/html/header.phml` . 
But Magento is not reading the header file I created. It runs fine on localhost. I just want to know from where server is taking the header .phtml file .
 Same file works in localhost. I have used cache command and all css styles are lost and also the template header is not updated.

Any pointers to this will be much appreciated.

Comment: did you try to deploy the code on the server?

Comment: Yes Kashif its already on the server